# Why optimization problems cannot be solved by simple derivative?

Tags: reference-request, education, linear-programming, integer-programming

> Let $f(\cdot)$ be a linear function.
>
> $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$
>
> $\;\quad\;\mathbf{x}\;\rightarrow f(\mathbf{x})$.
>
> Let $\mathbf{A}$ be a matrix in $\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$.
>
> Let $\mathbf{b}=\left(b_1, b_2, \dotsc, b_m\right)^\mathrm{T}$ be a vector in $\mathbb{R}^{m}$.
>
> The following problem $(P)$:
>
> $\mathrm{maximize}\;\;\; f(\mathbf{x})$
>
> subject to: $\;\;\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}\leq \mathbf{b}$.
>
> is a $0$-$1$ binary programming problem or a linear programming problem depending on $\mathbf{x}$ if $\mathbf{x}\in\{0, 1\}^n$ or $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n$.
>
> Problem $(P)$ is also hard to solve or easy to solve depending on $\mathbf{x}$ if $\mathbf{x}\in\{0, 1\}^n$ or $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

My question is the following: It is a very basic question. May be wrong one but I really need a clarification.

- If $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n$, why we do not simply calculate the derivative of $f(\cdot)$ at point $\mathbf{x}$ and we see its minimum and maximum and verify the constraints and solve $(P)$?
- If $\mathbf{x}\in\{0, 1\}^n$, why we cannot do the same thing?
- Is the derivative make things complicated?
- Does the derivative exists if $\mathbf{x}\in\{0, 1\}^n$?

Please any explanation. And thank you very much for your help.

EDIT: The function $f(\cdot)$ could be nonlinear and has a non-constant derivative. This AFAIK makes the problem even more complex. The problem becomes $0$-$1$ nonlinear binary  programming or nonlinear programming problem. Still the derivative cannot solve $(P)$?

Comment: If $f$ is linear, the derivative is constant, so it tells you little about the solution.

Comment: Thanks. But if $f$ is quadratic the problem gets more complicated in terms of complexity (AFAIK). Is the derivative also not a way to solve the problem? Why?

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. The derivative may be used as part of an algorithm that solves the problem. Even if you have a convex quadratic cost, the solution **must** depend on the constraints in some way, so it is unrealistic to expect that the derivative of the cost will provide a general, constraint-independent solution. (I may be misunderstanding your questions.)

Comment: No. You understand the question. The thing is: if the derivative gives me the set of points where $f(\cdot)$ is maximum, say. Then why we do not simply explore this set of points and verify the constraints to get the optimal one? I mean why people try to find heuristics and things like this?

Comment: If a point is an unconstrained maximum and also satisfies the constraints then it is a solution. But it is 'unlikely' that the unconstrained maximum, if it exists,  will satisfy the constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $n=2$ and $f(x)=x_1+x_2$, so $f$ is always increasing in both $x_1$ and $x_2$.  So the problem then is to find all combinations of $x_1,x_2$ that satisfy the inequality constraints and see which one yields the highest value of $f$.  In practice, what you do is that you implicitly cycle through different combinations of constraints in an intelligent way, making each constraint in the combination binding, verifying the others, and comparing $f$-values.